# Measure the time with time.time() and Keydown

Tags: python, date, time, pygame

I got sounds that I play from a list called `sounds`. It plays a sound, store the time when the sound is played in `start`, waits 6 seconds and plays the next sound from the list. Now I want to capture a reaction time between these 6 seconds with a keydown. If the condition is true then I click the button and it captures the time and store it in `end`. Then, the difference between `end` and `start` should give me the result. The problem is, that it does not measure the time right. It always gives me millisconds, even if I way longer bfore I click. I wonder what I am doing wrong here?

```
start = time.time()

    for i in range(len(arr)):
        pygame.mixer.music.load(sounds[i])
        pygame.mixer.music.play()

            for e in pygame.event.get():
                if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if e.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:

                        if condition:
                            end = time.time()
                            diff = end - start

            while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
                  time.sleep(6)
```

Comment: nobody can help?

Comment: Should the user press the button as soon as the sound plays?

Comment: yep, while these 6 seconds. But i think that time.sleep(6) is the problem, because it seems this will pause the whole program and you cannot do anything while this time

Comment: Is this question a duplicate of your new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53802710/how-to-meassure-time-in-python)? Then I think it would be better to delete one of them.

Comment: Yes, `time.sleep` will pause the whole program, so the user can't press buttons/keys anymore during that time.

Comment: Yeah, it is similiar, but different problem.

Comment: Is there a solution to interact while the sleeping time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest solution would be to reset the start time when the next sound starts playing.

```
import time
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray12')
SOUND = pg.mixer.Sound('a_sound.wav')

start = time.time()

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                diff = time.time() - start
                print(diff)

    passed_time = time.time() - start
    pg.display.set_caption(str(passed_time))
    if passed_time > 6:
        start = time.time()  # Reset the start time.
        SOUND.play()

    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pg.quit()
```

Comment: hey,  `SOUND = pg.mixer.Sound('a_sound.wav')` is not working. I think you have to load the sound first ?

Comment: It loads the sound file and creates a sound object which you can play by calling its `play` method. Is your filename/path correct? Does it print an error message?

Comment: I just put the sound file into the same folder like the program is. And it gives me an error. Usually i use `pygame.mixer.music.load(sounds[i]), pygame.mixer.music.play()`. Which works to play sounds,  but in this case it is not the right solution?

Comment: Please post the error message/traceback. I guess the filename or path is not correct. And print `os.listdir()` to check if the file is there.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/untitled/test2.py", line 9, in <module>
    SOUND = pg.mixer.Sound('a.mp3')
pygame.error: Unable to open file 'a.mp3'`

Comment: Pygame has sometimes problems with mp3 files. Check out if a different format (for example .ogg or .wav) works.

Comment: Yep, i just converted the mp3 into a wav and it worked!!

Comment: Hey skrx, your help has been incredible. I wish to ask you one last question. In my code from the beginning I loaded the sounds form a list called `sounds`. How can i modify your solution to play `sounds[0]`, after 6 seconds `sounds[1]`, after 6 seconds `sounds[2]`ect?

Comment: You just need an index variable which has to be incremented after the 6 seconds (use modulo to create a cycle `index %= len(sounds)`). A nice alternative would be [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle).

Comment: Thanks. Could you help me one last time? I tried it with a for loop which includes the index but it does not work

Comment: You don't need a for loop just increment the index after `if passed_time > 6:`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185325/discussion-between-skrx-and-ddd).