# How to measure time in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, time, pygame

I want to start my program, measure the time when the program starts and then wait some seconds, push a button (K_RIGHT) and messure the time when I push the button. I am using Pygame to registrate the Keydown. But in my code below it does not registrate my Keydown. What I am doing wrong here?

```
start = time.time()
for e in pygame.event.get():
    if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if e.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
           end= time.time()
           diff = end-start
```

Comment: The user shouldn't be able to push the button during the waiting time?

Comment: The user should be able to, i am just not sure how to solve it. Tried time.sleep(), but that was wrong.

Comment: instead of using time module try using pygame inbuilt time module ie.      pygame.time.clock()  equivalent to time.time(). try using pygame inbuild functions.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but does it makes any difference if the function is a equivalent?

Comment: @ddd functionality level not much, coding level too much (more pythonic way) but  you are using pygame as core component then it is usual practice to use that package inbuilt function as more as you can . more clean code.

Comment: Thanks man, do you have maybe an idead for my problem?

Comment: @ddd Please post a [minimal, runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (and make sure that the code is indented correctly). It looks like your program should actually compute the correct time difference.

Comment: @prashantrana I think you meant [pygame.time.get_ticks](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks).

Comment: I've posted a working example, but as far as I can see, your code should work as well.

Comment: @skrx yeah i meant the pygame.time.get_ticks()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a minimal, complete example that prints the correct time difference. The passed time is just the difference between `time.time()` (now) and the start time.

You could use [`pygame.time.get_ticks`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) instead of `time.time` as well (it returns the time in milliseconds instead of seconds).

```
import time
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray12')

start = time.time()

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                diff = time.time() - start
                print(diff)

    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pg.quit()
```

Comment: Wow, it works!! I would like to ask you: For what you use time.clock() in this case? And while using "while not done" loop? Is itneeded in this case?

Comment: The pygame.time.Clock is used to limit the framerate, otherwise the program would run as fast as possible. `clock.tick(60)` limits it to 60 frames per second in this case. -- Yes, the while loop is necessary.

Comment: For what reason? If I understand right, it only looks if Pygame is open or not? And also pg.display.flip() is not really needed, I am right?

Comment: Without the loop the program would be done immediately and the window would be closed. -- Yes, if you don't want to draw anything you can remove `pg.display.flip()` and `screen.fill(BG_COLOR)`.